# ConTeXt: How to make color derivation acts like LaTeX xcolor package

Tags: color, context

Trying to use color derivation as define [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definecolor), I fail to get any closer to what `xcolor` provides.

For exemple, this is what I get in LaTeX with `xcolor`:

[image: xcolor]

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{atestbox}{colback=red!20, colframe=red!20}

\begin{document}
  \begin{atestbox}
    A box.  
  \end{atestbox}
\end{document}
```

and here what I get in ConTeXt with color derivation:

[image: context color derivation]

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\definecolor[ColorA][1.0(red)]
\definecolor[myred02][0.2(ColorA)]
\definecolor[myred08][0.8(ColorA)]

\starttext
\framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=myred02]
        {\color[white]{0.2(red) derivation}}

\framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=myred08]
        {\color[white]{0.8(red) derivation}}
\stoptext
```

I tried to use all possible settings (and combination of them) from `\definecolor` (saturation, hue, brightness, transparency, etc...) but can't figure out how to do it.

Seems that I might have to use [tikz](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/TikZ).
However I don't know how to define a color with tikz and use it outside of a tikz picture or node (like frames or MetaFun).

[image: tikz]

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[tikz]

\definecolor[ColorA][1.0(red)]
\definecolor[myred02][ColorA!20] % or \definecolor[myred02][red!20]

\starttext
\framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=myred02]
        {\color[white]{red!20}}
\stoptext
```

`\pgfutil@definecolor` as mentionned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57016/213111) gives me compile errors.

Comment: derivation seems to mix with black, but you want a mix with white. It doesn't look as if context would support arbitrary color mixing, but you could always use xcolor to find out the rgb  or cmyk values and use them to define the context color.

Comment: Well, this is what I am already doing but this "solution" isn't really great for reusability. If I change a main color I have to change all derived ones.

Comment: According to the [colors manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/colors-mkiv.pdf) (Sec 1.16, page 23), to enable xcolor style colors you need `\enabledirectives[colors.pgf]`. But that gives different color than your example. I don't know how xcolors is supposed to work, but perhaps you can check the implementation in `colo-imp.lua` (line 397) and suggest an improved parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a bit digging on the context mailing list excavated this syntax which seems to do color mixing. But the exact rules are a bit unclear and it would probably be a good idea to ask on the context mailing list if this syntax is still supported and where it is documentated:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[tikz]

\definecolor[ColorA] [1.0(red)]
\definecolor[myred02][0.8(ColorA,white)] % 
\starttext
\tikz\node[fill=red!20]{abc};

\framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=myred02]
        {\color[white]{red!20} }
\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Thanks! I wonder why `0.8` for ConTeXt and not `0.2` since it's `!20` for xcolor?

Comment: I have no idea and as I wrote I even don't know if the syntax is intended to work. Better ask.

Comment: My guess is that it is mimicking how colors are mixed in metapost. For example, `0.8[red, white]` in metapost will give a color `0.2red + 0.8whilte`.

Comment: It is indeed following metapost color interpolation. See Sec 1.10 (pg 18) of the [color manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/colors-mkiv.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

From the [ConTeXt color manual](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/colors-mkiv.pdf): you can use

```
\enabledirectives[colors.pgf]

\definecolor[pgfcolora][red!50!blue]

\starttext
\framed[background=color, backgroundcolor=pgfcolora]
        {\color[white]{red!20} }
\stoptext
```

[image: xcolor]

Comment: `red!80!white` (which following metapost color interpolation) returns exactly the same result as the `xcolor` `red!20`.

Comment: @dpi Yes, it's not a perfect clone of the `xcolor` syntax. The main focus seems to be to offer mixing by exclamation mark.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to have some limitations too. For example I can't find a (simple) way to compose colors like here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482177/213111. But it's still a good start for some hacks!